# deducing $\lnot B \implies \lnot A$ from $A \implies B$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

One way how to prove a statement of the form $A \implies B$ is to presume that $A$ is true and deduce $B$. Lets have $A \implies B$ and lets assume that $\text{not}~B$ is true. $A$ is true or it is false (duh). If it were true, $B$ would also be true. However, we know that $B$ is not true and therefore $A$ must not be true either. We conclude $\lnot B \implies \lnot A$.

The other direction follows similarly.

1. Is my deduction sound?
2. Is there a more formal way to see these two are equivalent?

Comment: 1. Yes; 2. Use a [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table)

Comment: Yes, it's called the contrapositive. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive

Comment: Truth table? I would rather eat earwax than use a truth table...I never grew to like them.

Comment: @Oliver Bel: thanks for the link, I must have some deformation from this site, as I am reading "a simple proof using a definition of conditional" inside a wikipedia article, and I am saying to myself, this is good. Where can I upvote it? :-D

Comment: Proof by complete exhaustion beats earwax any day.

Comment: @copper.hat: I guess it depends on the alternatives open to you.

Comment: @Adam: Certainly a *less* formal, rough & ready way to show this is to use the method of analytic tableaux. It's very quick and can be translated into a formal proof with ease. I recommend learning how to use it; it's a panacea for this sort of thing (and faster than a truth table).

Comment: @Shaun: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, indeed, you've informally argued using a proof by contradiction.

(1) Given $A \rightarrow B$.

- (2) Assume $\lnot B$.

  - (3) Assume $A$.
  - (4) Then $B\;$ ((1) & (3), modus ponens)
  - (5) Then $\lnot B \land B\;$ ((2) & (4) $\land$-Introduction)
  - (6) $\perp\;$ Contradiction. (5)
- (7) Therefore $\lnot A\;$ ((3) - (6), $\lnot$-Introduction)

(8) Therefore $\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A\;$ (2-7)

Similarly, we can deduce $A\rightarrow B$ if given that $\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A$.

With both directions proven, we will have then proven (by natural deduction) the equivalence of an implication and its [contrapositive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition): $$A \rightarrow B \iff \lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A$$

Comment: Nice job showing steps and rationale +1

Comment: It might be better to rewrite 2 as "assume not $(A\to B)$." and then (3) as "then $A$ and not $B$." The user commented [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574907/proof-by-contradiction-making-more-than-one-assumption) that he thought you were making two assumptions, and I can see why. You're really only assuming one thing.

Comment: @rshwieb No, I *am* making two assumptions. One to arrive at a contradiction (innermost) so we can assert $\lnot A$, and the other to prove that from the assumption $\lnot B$, it follows that $\lnot A$: $\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A$

Comment: @amWhy OK, I reread and see what's going on. Sorry for the fuss.

Answer (score 2):

@amWhy gives the standard Natural Deduction proof. And note that it does not, repeat NOT, depend on the assumption that "A is true or false". That's significant. the inference from $A \to B$ to its contrapositive $\neg B \to \neg A$ is valid in intuitionistic logic where we don't have the law of excluded middle. So your informal argument wen't wrong by suggesting that the law of excluded middle was involved, even though you didn't actually depend on it.

Comment: Yep, I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

Formally, negation can be defined (and often is defined) by saying that $\neg P$ means $P \to \bot$ where $\bot$ is a 0-ary logical connective denoting absurdity.
So if you have $A \to B$ and $\neg B$ then you have $A \to B$ and $B \to \bot$, and we can combine these implications to get $A \to \bot$, which by definition is $\neg A$.

Note that the assumption "$A$ is true or false" is not needed, nor is any other application of the law of excluded middle.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the same solution as given by `amWhy`, but written in a format that makes the assumptions a bit more explicit (I prefer it for that reason).

Format:
col 1 = assumptions,
col 2 = line number,
col 3 = derived formula,
col 4 = the numbers used are all line numbers, except for numbers in "[]", which are the assumption numbers that get discharged

We want to show: $A \rightarrow B \vdash \neg B \rightarrow \neg A$
\begin{align*}
1     & &(1) & &A \rightarrow B  & &A\\
2     & &(2) & &\neg B           & &A\\
3     & &(3) & &A                & &A\\
1,3   & &(4) & &B                & &\rightarrow{}E\  1,3\\
1,2,3 & &(5) & &\bot             & &\neg{}E\  2,4\\
1,2   & &(6) & &\neg A           & &\neg{}I\  5[3]\\
1     & &(7) & &\neg B \rightarrow\neg A           & &\rightarrow{}I\  6[2]
\end{align*}