# proof by contradiction - making more than one assumption

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have a pet peeve with a proof by contradiction. Such proofs begin by an assumption which is shown to lead to a contradiction thereby leading us to conclude that our initial assumption must have been wrong.

However, it often happens that we make more than one assumption in the course of the proof by contradiction. My question is: How can we know which assumption is responsible for the contradiction?

See amWhys answer in [deducing $\lnot B \implies \lnot A$ from $A \implies B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574747/deducing-textnotb-implies-textnota-from-a-implies-b) - she makes two assumptions: not B and A.

Comment: It seems to me that it would depend very heavily on the circumstances of the proof.

Comment: if there's an contradiction under nested assumptions, then at least one of the assumptions are false. *Assuming* any of them (is true), you can conclude at least one of the rest are false.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you assume $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ and manage to derive a contradiction, then you have a proof by contradiction of *each* of the following theorems (which are all logically equivalent):

$$ A\land B \land C \implies \neg D $$
$$ A\land B \land D \implies \neg C $$
$$ A\land C \land D \implies \neg B $$
$$ B\land C \land D \implies \neg A $$

Often it will only be one of these you're actually interested in, but you're free to choose to state any or all of them as a conclusion once you've done the work.

Comment: ...or more symmetrically: $\lnot A \lor \lnot B \lor \lnot C \lor \lnot D$, or $\lnot(A \land B \land C \land D)$.

Comment: Under what conditions is this true? Suppose A states that x=1, B states that x=2, and C states that y=1, and D that z=1. A and B contradict each other directly so we cannot use that to learn anything about C and D, right? I want to understand what assumptions we need to make for proof by contradiction to be valid. Notationally, we usually act as if our last stated assumption is the one that a contradiction invalidates, but I don't see the basis for this in general, since early assumptions might already contradict each other.

Answer (score 6):

Usually, we structure a proof so that the assumption we want to show leads to a contradiction is the *last* assumption made prior to reaching the contradiction.

So we may at times *nest* assumptions, and the innermost assumption leading to the most immediate ensuing contradiction is the assumption we can then "throw out" (negate).

So, for example, often times we commit ourselves to certain assumptions (e.g., hypotheses, premises, or the antecedent of a conditional we want to prove, etc.), and then follow by "assuming for the sake of contradiction that $p$...". We then seek a contradiction that follows from having just assumed $p$: it may contradict an assumption/hypothesis which we had previously committed ourselves to, earlier in the proof. If/When we arrive at a contradiction, we can then use negation introduction to conclude $\lnot p$, and the assumption $p$ is then considered "discharged." $\lnot p$ then becomes a valid premise which can be used later in the proof.

If you look at the structure of the proof you linked to, you'll see that assumptions are literally "nested," to help identify the logic of the proof, and also the *scope* of the two assumptions.

Comment: Does this nesting of our last assumption express a logical assertion about the relations among the non-nested assumptions, or is it just a notational convenience to make it easier to point out that it's only the last assumption we intend to invalidate? Do we need to show the non-nested assumptions do not contradict each other? (This is a restatement of my comment on the selected answer, I think.)

Answer (score 0):

That's the way implication works, the only way to break
$$ A \implies B$$
is if you have
$$ \mbox{True} \implies \mbox{False}$$

So what do we do, we assume $\mbox{Not } B$ is true and $A$ is also true.  If this leads to a contradiction, then the *implication* is true.